# Unable to use copy on Virtual Machine creation - Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, infrastructure-as-code

i am trying to create multiple virtual machines frrom a list in a variables file. I have a list with two virtual machine names. I can create them, however when i try and use the count commands, it doesn't loop through correctly to assign the nics to the vm's. Please see below. The error i receive is 'Call to function "element" failed: Cannot use element function with an empty list.

```
    resource "azurerm_network_interface" "VM01" {
  count               = "${length(var.Numberofdcs)}"
  name                = "${element(var.Numberofdcs, count.index)}-nic"
  location            = "${var.Location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.ProdInfraRG.name}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ipconfig"
    subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.ProdVNet.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "VMCreation" {
  count                 = "${length(var.Numberofdcs)}"
  name                  = "${element(var.Numberofdcs, count.index)}"
  location              = "${var.Location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.ProdInfraRG.name}"
  network_interface_ids = "${element(azurerm_network_interface.VM01.*.id, count.index)}"
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnFqI.png)

Comment: Error heavily implies that `var.Numberofdcs` is an empty list (includes being an empty string).

Comment: Yes, but the same Numberofdcs is used to create the nics and it does this as a loop. So not sure why it doesn't work the same when looping to apply the nics to the vms.